# startup-script not as root (google cloud compute, ubuntu 14.04 VM)

Tags: ubuntu, cloud, virtual-machine, google-cloud-platform, startupscript

The default of the startup script is to run as root, I need to run the startup script as a specific user (the one used to create the image for the instance).  I've tried all possible variations of su, etc, but when specifying that way, execution fails with no output.  I might just be missing something stupid, but any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69628836/10375049

Answer (score 6):

For anyone else having problem and looking for a solution.. I had the same issue. I created another script /opt/c2d/startup-script-user and called it from the default start script using su like this:

```
su - nonrootuser -c '/opt/c2d/startup-script-user.sh'
```

Comment: You have to add new user nonrootuser before use it: useradd nonrootuser

Comment: nonrootuser could be your main user

Answer (score 0):

i am trying to run selenium scraping scripts using start script. when i run the script as noon root user it will work fine. When i trigger it from start script it will not allow the chrome to crate webDriver due to which chrome is crahsed so what i found the solutions is:

first convert the root user to noon root user using su - user_name then run the .sh file for executing the scripts.

```
echo "converting root user to non_root user"
su - Mehar -c 'cd /home/mehar/rfq_scraper_app && ls -la && ./start_django_server.sh' || echo "Failed to start Django server"
echo "Script execution is ended"
```