# docker login with root user on Container-VM Image

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-container-os

This is question about Google Container VM Image(beta)
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/vm-image/

I logged in a instance made by Container VM image.
And run:

```
sudo /usr/share/google/dockercfg_update.sh
```

That script above does `docker login` to private container registry.

It causes error:

```
/usr/share/google/dockercfg_update.sh: 27: cannot create /root/.dockercfg: Read-only file system
```

`/root` directory seems to be read-only in the container-vm.
**How can I `docker login` by root user?**

Answer (score 5):

Since /root is read-only, your credentials cannot be stored there. You can add a non-root user to 'docker' group and run `/usr/share/google/dockercfg_update.sh` and `docker login` as that user.

From https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/vm-image/#accessing_private_google_container_registry

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G docker ${USER}
$ exec sudo su ${USER}
$ /usr/share/google/dockercfg_update.sh
$ docker pull gcr.io/YOUR_PROJECT/YOUR_IMAGE
```

> How can I 'docker login' by root user

If you must invoke `docker login` or `/usr/share/google/dockercfg_update.sh` as `root` user (not recommended), a hacky way is to prefix `HOME=/home/chronos/` to your commands. Ex:

```
# as 'root' user
$ HOME=/home/chronos/ /usr/share/google/dockercfg_update.sh
$ HOME=/home/chronos/ docker pull gcr.io/YOUR_PROJECT/YOUR_IMAGE
```

Answer (score 2):

`/root` is read-only, so you can't run docker commands because you are not able to store the docker config (or any other files) generated by any [authentication methods](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication).

The solution is to run the docker commands as another user in order to save docker config properly.

Below are the steps to follow:

**1) authenticate to Container Registry on a system where Cloud SDK is not available:**

With an existing user (*`MYUSER`*):

```
sudo -u MYUSER docker-credential-gcr configure-docker
```

With a new generated user (*`NEWUSER`*):

```
sudo useradd -m NEWUSER
sudo -u NEWUSER docker-credential-gcr configure-docker
```

The `-u` flag executes the command as the specified user.

`docker-credential-gcr configure-docker` stores your credentials in your user home directory (an alternative to `docker login`). This way, you can use Docker's command-line tool to interact directly with Container Registry.

**2) Create the docker group (if not exists) and add your user (required with *`NEWUSER`* or *`MYUSER`* with no permission to run Docker's commands):**

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker NEWUSER
```

**3) If needed, restart the docker daemon:**

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

In the end, you can access the docker images placed in your private container registry as *`MYUSER`* or *`NEWUSER`*. If you would like to run dockers:

```
sudo -u MYUSER docker run ........
```

The commands reported here work fine also in a *startup-script* and without the requirement of passwords.